# Como validar acentos y la letra ñ?

Tags: jquery

Poseo lo siguiente lo cual no acepta caracteres especiales, como podria permitir los signos de aceptuacion áéíóú y la letra ñ

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)$/
```

Comment: Se nota que no acepta, pero has intentado algo??

Comment: Añade los caractered en la lista individualmente.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ ]+$/`

Answer (score 2):

Hola simplemente agregue esto

```js
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\sÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúÑñ]+)$/;

console.log(regex.test('cáñamo'))
console.log(regex.test('CÁÑAMO'))
```

Si no le interesa permitir mayúsculas solo quítelas de la expresión